# Как скопировать последнюю строку файла в другой файл, Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Есть лог файл, который обновляется каждую секунду, нужно копировать из него периодически последнюю строку, вывод в терминал получается, делаю так:

```
cat /tmp/ffmpeg-log.log | tail -n 1
```

Выводится одна, последняя строка, а вот когда нужно скопировать в другой файл эту строку, делаю так:

```
cat /tmp/ffmpeg-log.log | tail -n 1 > ffmpeg.txt
```

так в этот файл ffmpeg.txt копируется строк 50-60, а то и больше, подскажите как правильно скопировать одну, последнюю строку.

Comment: может `echo 'cat /tmp/ffmpeg-log.log | tail -n 1' >> ffmpeg.txt`? Только обычные кавычки замените на обратные

Comment: все правильно, и ваш код и мой, проблема была в самом файле.

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, типичный *useless use of cat*.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko `echo 'tail -n 1 < /tmp/ffmpeg-log.log' >> ffmpeg.txt` - а теперь?

Comment: А вы пробовали? Работает? Да и выглядит теперь useless use of echo. О, а я и не заметил этот бред в первоначальном варианте!

Comment: @AndyShevchenko пробовал, работает. Предложите своё решение

Comment: `man tail`: **tail [OPTION]... [FILE]...**, дальше объяснять? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: @AndyShevchenko Спасибо, понятно: `tail -n 1 /tmp/ffmpeg-log.log > ffmpeg.txt`. Но Вы могли бы указать на это одним комментарием, а так  получился фарс.

Comment: Так я сразу и написал, useless use of cat. Это такая идиома. Даже ссылку вам привёл,  на будущее.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko да, спасибо, я уже ознакомился. Полезно, признаю.